# Converting the /dev/ttyUSB to com port to use it with Wine in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, wine

I have some software which runs on Windows. I installed Wine and ran it in Linux. It works fine but the issue is it communicates with a serial port. Therefore the only option I can choose are `com1`, `com2`, …

But my device on the Linux machine is actually located at the `/dev/ttyUSBn` location. How do I use the above software in Linux Ubuntu?

I have tried `ln -s /dev/ttyUSBn COM1` in the `~/.wine/dosdevices/`. It does not appear to work.

Answer (score 15):

Starting from Wine 2.8, the simple symlink-editing method of configuration doesn't work. One has to configure COM ports by editing Wine registry. From [Wine User's Guide/Other Things to Configure/Serial and Parallel Ports](https://wiki.winehq.org/index.php?title=Wine_User%27s_Guide&oldid=2519#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports):

> To override Wine's default device mapping, run `wine regedit` and create string entries in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine\Ports` where the entry name is the Windows device name and the entry value is the path to the Unix device. Continuing with the above example, to make COM1 the first USB-attached serial port, create an entry with the name `COM1` and the value `/dev/ttyUSB0`. You might also want to create an entry named `COM5` with no value to remove the `COM5` device which is now a duplicate of `COM1`. After editing the registry, shut down Wine with `wineserver -k` and the next time Wine runs a program, your changes will take effect.

Comment: On macOS to get serial port work under Wine 4.x, we need to use both methods explained here, create symbolic link + insert new string value in the Windows registry. Using only one of that will not work.

Answer (score 5):

Symlinks should work; however, they must be located in `~/.wine/dosdevices/`, not in any random directory. The [WineHQ article](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/misc-things-to-configure) also shows the names in lower-case.

> #### [4.3.1. Serial and Parallel Ports](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/misc-things-to-configure#AEN715)
>
> Serial and parallel port configuration is very similar to drive configuration - simply create a symbolic link in `~/.wine/dosdevices` with the name of the device. Windows serial ports follow a naming convention of the word "com" followed by a number, such as `com1`, `com2`, etc. Similarly, parallel ports use "lpt" followed by a number, such as `lpt1`. You should link these directly to the corresponding Unix devices, such as `/dev/ttyS0` and `/dev/lp0`. For example, to configure one serial port and one parallel port, run the following commands:
>
> ```
> ln -s /dev/ttyS0 com1
> ln -s /dev/lp0 lpt1
> ```

Comment: Yes. Thats definitely where I put it. I also tried changing the permissions of the com files and also added the registry edits according to the wiki. I still have no luck

Comment: Perhaps update the answer, given [Ruslan's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/619528/converting-the-dev-ttyusb-to-com-port-to-use-it-with-wine-in-linux/1471614#1471614)?

Answer (score 2):

it might be caused by a permission issue.

The tty devices are usually readable/writable by a specific group like `dialout`. Add yourself to that group using the following command finally logout and log back in

```
gpasswd -a $USER dialout
```

Honestly, it would probably be better to first check if your user belongs to the dialout group. Use this command to show the groups in which your user is present

```
groups $USER
```

If `dialout` is not there, then test the approach by temporarily changing the permissions of the `ttyACMX/ttyUSBX` file in `/dev` folder

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACMX_OR_ttyUSBX
```

Re run your program using wine and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, MS software using `GetCommConfig()` under Wine needs a registry key explictly set if the automatic detection feature described in https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports doesn't automatically detect your port.

Try setting a registry key in `~/.wine/system.reg` like this:

```
...
[Hardware\\Devicemap\\Serialcomm] 1231984861
"Serial0"="COM1"
...
```

It worked for me with my `ln -s /dev/tty.usbmodemFD121 ~/.wine/dosdevices/COM1` device.

Comment: (1) Answers should not ask questions.  (2) Where are you getting this?  I can’t find `Devicemap` or `Serialcomm` at [the Useful Registry Keys page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Useful_Registry_Keys) that you linked to.

Comment: I needed a `~/.wine/system.reg` hardware key like this per https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB/issues/359#issuecomment-350054880

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the links you have created, make sure the user is in the correct user groups. From [Wine User's Guide/Other Things to Configure/Serial and Parallel Ports](https://wiki.winehq.org/index.php?title=Wine_User%27s_Guide&oldid=2519#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports):

> Make sure you have the needed rights to access your computer's serial and parallel ports. On Linux, a user must typically be a member of the **`sys` or `dialout` group** to access serial ports